# determine the general solution of $y^{2/3}+y'^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the general solution of $y^{2/3}+y'^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$. I have this question in my workbook and the answer for this is $y = a\cos^{3}t$ and $x= 3(cot(t)+t)$ which i think they set t as y' but I'm not sure about it and I don't know how to lead to the answer, I tried the polar coordinates but it didn't seem to work. Can I get a hint or a solution for this problem? Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is derivative of cosx and what is cos^2 x+sin^2 x

Comment: No, the general solution is not $y(x)=a\cos^3 x$.  In fact this $y(x)$ doesn't satisfy $y(x)^{2/3}+y'(x)^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$ at all.

Comment: Hi @user10354138, please see my answer below.  I'm using a standard process to derive the solution, and it seems to agree with the OP's suggestion.  Let me know if you see any issues.  Thanks.

Comment: @Doug $y'^{2/3}\neq z'^2$ because taking cube roots and then differentiate is different from differentiate and then take cube root.

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad hi is that a hint? thank you!

Comment: @user10354138 hi i think in the answer they set t as y', and ịn the answer it said x = 3(cot(t) +t)

Answer (score 4):

In cartesian coordinates, there is a solution : let $y(x)=a\,z(x)$ and switch variables to obtain (this is probably only *one* of the solutions)
$$x'(z)=\frac{1}{\left(1-z^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}}$$ which separable.
$$x+C=\int \frac{dz}{\left(1-z^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}}=\color{red}{I}$$
$$z^{2/3}=t^2 \quad\implies \quad I=3\int \frac{t^2}{\left(1-t^2\right)^{3/2}}\,dt$$
$$t=\sin(u)\quad\implies \quad I=3\int \tan^2(u)\,du=3\int (\sec^2(u)-1)\,du=3(\tan(u)-u)$$

Undo the substitutions to obtain

$$\large\color{blue}{\frac x 3+C=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{z}}{\sqrt{1-z^\frac{2}{3}}}-\arcsin\left(\sqrt[3]{z}\right)}$$ which cannot be inversed (except using series).

Comment: Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, insert polar coordinates. $y(t)=a\cos^3(\theta(t))$, $y'(t)=-a\sin^3(\theta(t))$. Now take the derivative of the first equation to compare against the second equation
$$
-3a\theta'(t)\sin(\theta(t))\cos^2(\theta(t))=y'(t)=-a\sin^3(\theta(t))
\\~\\ \implies
3\theta'(t)=\tan^2(\theta(t))
$$
Now it is obvious that $\theta(t)=t$ is not  solution.

Comment: I think that, in cartesian coordinates, there is a explicit solution for $x(y)$ (but not what is said)

Comment: I think it is the same, only phase shifted. My calculations would continue with $$\frac13=\frac{1-\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\theta'=(\csc^2\theta-1)\theta'=(-\cot(\theta)-\theta)'$$

Comment: I think that we fully agree. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you but i think they set t as y' in the answer, and according to the answer  $x=3(cot(t) +t)$

Comment: @randomguy : What is $x$? You get $t=-3(\cot\theta+\theta+C)$ which you can insert into the parametrization to get $$y(-3(\cot(\theta)+\theta+C))=a\cos^3(\theta).$$

Comment: @LutzLehmann oh i get it thank you so much